# Run a set of functions in a detached screen

Tags: bash, shell-script, gnu-screen, function

Is it possible to call a bunch of functions within a detached screen that are defined elsewhere in the script? For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

Method1() { ... }
Method2() { ... }
Method3() { ... }
Method4() { ... }

cd "$DST_DIR"

screen -dm -S "$(date +%s)_PROCESS" -L {
  Method1
  Method2
  Method3
  Method4
}
```

Comment: (the common term for those Methods is `function`)

Comment: run all methods (functions) in other function and then screen will have to run only this one function which will run other functions (methods)